# Apache POI. style.setBackgroundColor is not working

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("test sheet");
Row row1 = worksheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell0  = row1.createCell(0);
CellStyle testStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
testStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
cell0.setCellStyle(testStyle);
```

I`m trying to change background color of the cell to red. 
But actually the background color of the cell is not changing. It is still white

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing the line:

```
testStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

This will tell apache-poi how visible the color should be.

Answer (score 1):

If @XtremeBaumer's solution does not work, after adding that line please change this line. from

```
testStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
```

to

```
testStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
```

If you use Apache Poi ***HSSF*** this one more suitable.